# How to crawl vidoes with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I try to download videos from site. Now my spider can crawl images. But this can not download video.

I used FilesPipeline and some methods.

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
    for file_url in adapter["file_urls"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(file_url)
```

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    file_paths = [x["path"] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not file_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no files")
    adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
    adapter["file_paths"] = file_paths
    return item
```

Some files are downloaded but those are not video files...

Let me know how to crawl video with scrapy, Thank you!

[image]

Comment: "Video" is an overloaded concept on the web. _Specifically_, what do you mean by that?

Comment: first in question you should show real URL for this page and minimal working code so we could test it. Second you should check what you get in files - maybe you get HTML with warning for bots. You could also use `print()` to display values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging"